# Logging MSSQL Inserts

Tags: sql-server, logging, transactions, insert

I'm working with a Accounting software(that which cannot be named) my company purchased in spite of my strong recommendations not to. It uses a massive messy MsSQL database that may be the end of me..

In spite of paying thousands for said software it's completely closed & little to no support is offered. In order to complete an integration with our in house CRM I need to log/track the SQL queries that are being executed when doing things like creating a customer via their GUI. That way I can see the obvious inserts I've already duplicated & I assume 1-2 other inserts or updates that are happening but I am currently unaware of..

I've been able to log SQL selects no problem but that doesn't help me at all. I'm less familiar with MsSQL, I'm one of those linux guys using Postgres, Nginx & PHP for our CRM.

I've searched quite a bit for a way to log not only the INSERT transactions but the data being inserted as well to no avail so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Look into SQL Profiler or SQL trace. It's free.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175047.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can put an insert trigger on the tables.  You want to create a trigger FOR INSERT and have this trigger insert whatever details you want to keep into a new table.  You can do the same for Updates and deletes if you want.

Be aware that an insert trigger will react to a bulk insert as easily as one record at a time.  Build your code accordingly.